# Find Expectation of Product of Three Random Variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

I have two normal random variables $X$~$\mathcal{N}(\mu_X, \sigma^2_X)$ and $Y$~$\mathcal{N}(\mu_Y, \sigma^2_Y)$ and one discrete uniform random variable $\theta$~Unif$(a,b)$ whose mean $\mu_\theta$ and variance $\sigma^2_\theta$ are known. To be clear, $\theta$ is uniformly distributed over a finite number of $b-a+1$ integers $a,a+1,a+2,...,b-1,b$. I also have the following covariance matrix

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
    \sigma^2_X       & \sigma_{X,Y} & 0 \\
    \sigma_{X,Y}       & \sigma^2_Y & 0 \\
    0       & 0 & \sigma^2_\theta 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I am trying to determine $\mathbb{E} \Big[ X Y \sin2\theta \Big]$. In other words, I am trying to determine the expectation of the product of three random variables: $X$, $Y$, and $\sin2\theta$, the latter of which is a function of $\theta$.

I tried leveraging the formula for covariance as follows

$$ \mathbb{E}[V_1V_2] = \sigma_{V_1,V_2}  + \mathbb{E}[V_1]\mathbb{E}[V_2] $$

but this only returns the expectation of the product of two random variables. I could possibly define $A = XY$ and try to find $\mathbb{E}[A,\sin2\theta]$, but then I would need the covariance between $XY$ and $\sin2\theta$, which I don't have and unfortunately I don't believe I can assume independence between $\sin2\theta$ and the product $XY$.

Any thoughts on how to proceed? Or do I simply lack the info I need?

**NOTE:** I'm asking this question to assist in answering another question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4807083/find-variance-of-random-variable-w-cos-thetal-sin-theta-where-l-w-theta-ar/4807287#4807287) on the math SE. Feel free to tackle it directly if you wish.

Comment: $\theta$ takes on $b-a+1$ discrete values $a, a+1, a+2, ..., b-1, b$ with uniform probability. Thus, it has a probability mass function. And, yes $\sigma_{X,Y} = \sigma_{Y,X}$. I wrote it the way i did to keep notation consistent with rows and columns in the matrix

Comment: Without extra assumptions, mean and covariance alone do not determine the joint distribution of random variables. (A famous exception is when all the involved random variables are known to be jointly normal, in which case they do determine the joint distribution.) Since $\theta$ is not normal, you are not given enough information to determine $\mathbb{E}[XY\sin2\theta]$.

Comment: This what I thought. Thanks! Please list as answer!